# In Git Bash, unable to run "rails server"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Error: Could not find gem 'sass-rails <~> 4.0.2> x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine. Run 'bundle install' to replace missing gems.

---So I run 'bundle install' in Git Bash.

*It runs and I get a wall of text*

Error: Failed to build gem native extension

...

Error: An error occurred while installing atomic <1.1.16>, and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure than 'gem install atomic -v '1.1.16'' succeeds before installing

-- I have no idea how to install atomic -v 1.1.16 or sass-rails
-- Please help, thanks!

-- I was following the steps on installrails.com and I got stuck on: http://installrails.com/steps/see_it_live
--which is like the 3rd or 4th page of the guide.

**I got it to work on my Windows 8 Laptop, but not my Windows 7 Desktop. The above information (errors) refers to my Windows 7 Desktop.**

**Solved: I restarted my computer and Git Bash automatically retried to install the bundle when I opened it up and made a new rails file. It worked and now the rails server runs just fine.**

Comment: Here is the solution regarding atomic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291664/error-installing-atomic

Comment: It appears their issue was spaces in the directory, I checked mine. No spaces in mine.

Answer (score 1):

You should install development kit http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Download and install the DevKit depend on your ruby version. After then you can try to run `gem install atomic -v '1.1.16'`

Comment: Where do I extract the files to?

Comment: Just follow [this Instructions](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#installation-instructions)

Answer (score 0):

**I restarted my computer**, made a new sample rails file which automatically made Git Bash install the bundler. Then I was able to run 'rails server' with no problems.