# n error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.14), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291664/error-installing-atomic) the issue is the space in the file name ruby extconf.rb.

I am using OSX and I recently installed RVM. I don't think that should be causing any issues.

However I have no idea how to fix that! =c

```
± |master ✗| → bundle install --without production
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake 10.1.0
Using i18n 0.6.5
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.8.2


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

    bundle install --path vendor/bundle

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

Password:

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling atomic_reference.c
atomic_reference.c:53:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64(expect_value, new_value, &DATA_PTR(self))) {
        ^
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object atomic_reference.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [atomic_reference.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/d3/y59njq8j3y3f4mwz9gbn4sqc0000gn/T/bundler20140416-27601-fkq14n/atomic-1.1.14/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/d3/y59njq8j3y3f4mwz9gbn4sqc0000gn/T/bundler20140416-27601-fkq14n/atomic-1.1.14/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/atomic-1.1.14/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sept so many hours trying to fix this... Now I got it fixed!!!!
What I did:

I tried to reinstall the RVM and typed the below remove command.

rm -rf ~/.rvm

And then try "bundle install" command.  Then it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Updating ruby from 1.9 to 2.1 did the trick.